# Problema con tipo de datos de una consulta en un metodo asíncrono

Tags: c#, conversión-de-tipos, asincronismo

estoy realizando una consulta a la API de Woocommerce, para el posterior trato de estos datos.
La consulta la debo ejecutar asíncronamente, no entiendo demasiado bien el porqué, pero si no, no me devuelve ningún dato.
El caso es que al intentar recuperar los datos que me devuelve el método, me da error de tipo de datos, alguien me puede ayudar por favor ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WooCommerceNET;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2.Extension;

namespace woocommerce
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Product> Productes = LlistaProductes();    
        }
        async Task<List<Product>> LlistaProductes()
        {
            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://woocom.com/wp-json/wc/v2/", "ck_025d00ebc6f9f327d59e23b695da764cd51a4165", "cs_44017996f342bfaf48ae26981f7106bd330f4fff");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            var productes = await wc.Product.GetAll();
            return  productes;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Este es el error que me genera, no se como recuperar los datos que me devuelve el método LlistaProductes()

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp5wx.png]

Comment: Primero: La consultas siempre deberian ser asincronicas para que no te congele la pantalla. Segundo si no pones que error te da, es imposible saber, pero imagino que el problema debe venir por un json que te devuelve y vos lo queres pasar directamente a tu modelo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás tratando de guardar un resultado `Task<List<Product>>` en un `List<Product>` esto porque el método `LlistaProductes()` es asíncrono por lo que te regresa la tarea inmediatamente y no el resultado de la función porque no se ha ejecutado aún. La solución es esperar `(await)` a que se ejecute la función y retorne el valor esperado `List<Product>`. Tan solo debes hacer tu método `Form1_Load` asíncrono y usar `await` al llamar `LlistaProductes()`, tu código quedaría asi:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Product> Productes = await LlistaProductes();    
}
```